# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS upgrade : could not install nvidia-driver-470 / nvidia-driver-525

Tags: nvidia, upgrade

I was wondering if someone had the same problem as me when upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and how to solve it.

In summary, the issue is that I am not able to install the nvidia-dkms-525 driver, which if I'm not wrong, is the correct version for the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS kernel.

I would much appreciate it if someone can through some lights to find a solution for this. TIA

Here you are some details about the issue:

**$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-525 is already the newest version (525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nvidia-dkms-525 (525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-525.60.11 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-525.60.11 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-525.60.11 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-56-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-56-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-525.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.60.11/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-525 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-525 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-525:
 nvidia-driver-525 depends on nvidia-dkms-525 (<= 525.60.11-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-525 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-525 depends on nvidia-dkms-525 (>= 525.60.11); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-525 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-525 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-525
 nvidia-driver-525
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**$ less /var/crash/nvidia-dkms-525.0.crash**

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for nvidia-525.60.11 for kernel 5.15.0-56-generic (x86_64)
 Mon Jan  2 06:09:44 PM CET 2023
 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
 test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (               \
 echo >&2;                                                      \
 echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";          \
 echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
 echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";     \
 echo >&2 ;                                                     \
 /bin/false)
 
   ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
          include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
          Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
 
 make[1]: *** [Makefile:750: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
 make: *** [Makefile:82: modules] Error 2
DKMSKernelVersion: 5.15.0-56-generic
Date: Mon Jan  2 18:09:45 2023
Package: nvidia-dkms-525 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
PackageVersion: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
SourcePackage: nvidia-graphics-drivers-525
Title: nvidia-dkms-525 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1: nvidia kernel module failed to build
/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-525.0.crash (END)
```

**$ less /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.60.11/build/make.log**

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-525.60.11 for kernel 5.15.0-56-generic (x86_64)
Mon Jan  2 07:07:48 PM CET 2023
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make[1]: *** [Makefile:750: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:82: modules] Error 2
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.60.11/build/make.log (END)
```

**Here you are a pic with the error when the upgrading was in progress:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0SpM.jpg)

**And Here you are a pic with the errors in the start up process** (finally the OS starts, I can do login successfully, etc).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQrOE.jpg)

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys, I've not found a better way to attach the outputs as the Body is limited to 30000 characters and I'm trying to enter more than 40000.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYXpS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WBIk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anMDw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJpuy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVpv8.png)

**EDIT:**

It seems that all "rc" packages are already purged and in addition I have installed the nvidia-driver-525.

**$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-525 is already the newest version (525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

**$ dpkg -l | egrep '^rc'**

```
<EMPTY>
```

**$ apt list --installed | grep -i nvidia**

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnvidia-cfg1-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-525/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-egl-wayland1/jammy,now 1:1.1.9-1.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-56-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [installed]
linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-56-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-56-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-56-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/jammy,jammy,now 0.8.17.1 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/jammy,jammy,now 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

[image]

But still I'm getting similar errors in the start up process (finally the OS starts, I can login successfully, etc).

[image]

Please, any idea guys ?. I'm a bit lost with this issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `dkms status` and `dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|m|k|h]|'`

Comment: @nobody, your egrep has an extra pipe at end, messing up the search.  Looks like files are missing from the headers for the 5.15.0-56 kernel, according to the error message.

Comment: Oj did not see it 

Comment: Wow, what a lot of old kernel packages.  You should try sudo apt purge <pkgname> on all the kernel packages you show with lines starting with "rc".  Does look like the header package is missing for the 5.15.0-56, but might have missed it. A full reinstall periodically will help avoid this sort of leftover package problem.  Look into /lib/modules after the purges and see if any old dirs are left around for old kernels too, those sometimes get left.

Comment: Your DisplayLink driver block it. Please serch for evdi https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/391

Comment: Thanks guys.

I have uninstalled displaylink but the issue still remains.

Do you suggest then purge (apt purge <pkgname>) all packages of this search listing ?

`$ dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|m|k|h]' | egrep "^rc  "`

Or maybe all packages of this search listing ?

`$ dpkg -l | egrep "^rc  "`

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg -P` this removes all remaining obsolete conffiles.

Comment: I would suggest to remove any nvidia package and start fresh over Ubuntu driver gui.

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys for the suggestion. I'll keep you up to date when I do it.